# Wrap a long string in Rails while preserving urls?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails project I have the following code:

```
auto_link( h( wrap_long_string(post.text,50)  )).gsub(/\n/,"<br />")
```

`wrap_long_string` is defined as:

```
  def wrap_long_string(txt,col = 20)
    txt.gsub(/(.{1,#{col}})( +|$\n?)|(.{1,#{col}})/,
      "\\1\\3\n")
  end
```

This code is meant to display user-entered text while preventing users from messing up the layout of the page by entering a very long non-breaking string for example.

However, the act of breaking up long non-breaking strings also prevents the `auto_link` helper from working.

What I would like to do is to have the following text:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=ZGF&q=example&btnG=Search
```

turned into something like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaa <a href='http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=ZGF&q=example&btnG=Search'>http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=ZGF&q=example&btnG=Search</a>
```

Comment: By the way, using CSS you can do this for both the text and the links.  If you use a paragraph `p` HTML element, just set `word-wrap: break-word;` and it will work in IE5.5+ and all modern browsers.  There are some caveats like it won't work for `display: table-cell;` so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could define your own auto_link  (use the existing code in text_helper.rb as a model) to first scan for urls (and for emails), do the substitution, find the indices of where you've made substitutions, and then break the line in places that don't fall within those indices.

This should only require the existing autolink code along with a coupe of calls to index() and length().

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the order these are applied in, I'd suggested running the text through the auto-link helper and then through the long text breaker (and make that 'smart' enough to not count text in html tags as text :)). That should create the links, and I belive you can have 
 in between  tags without any ill consequences :)